# Does jQuery create a #! as part of the menu?

Tags: jquery, menu

The template we are using creates a #! in the menu links.  For example, http://www.clientwebsite/#!/about

It seems to defeat the SEO friendly links we were counting on from WordPress.
The template vendor says they are necessary for jQuery to work.
I don't believe that.

Can I use .htacess to remove them and still have the site work properly?

Comment: That would probably depend on the template software in question. What's the name of the software? I would imagine it's dependent on the way the templating engine was written/implemented. Without a name though, no one will be able to tell you for sure.

Comment: using a #! (otherwise known as a hashbang) is actually part of a good SEO practice. Do this for me: Does this url work? `http://www.clientwebsite/about/`? if it does, then your site is SEO friendly and probably uses ajax navigation properly.

Comment: The #! convention is not inherently required by jQuery.